# to attach excel file in smtp mail in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtpclient

I have an excel file in my solution with name **Book1.xlsx**.
I want to attach it to my mail and send it.

Here is my code:

```
public void mailer()
{      
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("np4652@gmail.com", "Si9369787348");
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath("excel/Book1.xlsx"));
    mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileName));           
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    mail.Subject = "status";
    mail.Body = "Today's list " + "<br/>" + Label1.Text;
    mail.To.Add("amit@lmscert.com");
    mail.From = new MailAddress("np4652@gmail.com");
    smtp.Send(mail);
}
```

But I get following error:

> An exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Could not find file 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Book1.xlsx'.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you checked path 'C:\Program Files\IIS Express\Book1.xlsx' file exist or not?
Please try to use relative path 'Server.MapPath("../excel/Book1.xlsx")' or 'Server.MapPath("~/excel/Book1.xlsx")'

Comment: Hello, @ravi shanker Check my code...

Comment: I tried both 'Server.MapPath("../excel/Book1.xlsx")' or 'Server.MapPath("~/excel/Book1.xlsx")' but it gives same error

Comment: @ravipolara where is your code

Comment: What is the **actual exact** path to `Book1.xlsx` on your file system?

Answer (score 2):

You're passing just the filename, which resolves to a relative path, being `C:\Program Files\IIS Express` because your code is running in IIS Express:

```
string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Server.MapPath("excel/Book1.xlsx"));
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileName));
```

You need to pass the full path, simply remove the `GetFileName()`:

```
string FileName = Server.MapPath("excel/Book1.xlsx");
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileName));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code in filepath

```
  string path = Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath, "excel/Book1.xlsx"); 
                            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(path);
```

Comment: "Try this" is not an answer. Explain what problem your suggestion solves.